if-up.d files does not have effect on ubuntu 24.04 LTS
EDIT: Ubuntu bug posted here
some time ago I wrote a detailed answer to fix an error for lowering MTU size for a cisco compatible VPN.
After upgrading to Ubuntu 24.04 LTS, I'm unable with the same steps to lower the MTU size.
In particular, if I run the following command from the terminal
sudo ifconfig your_tunnel_name mtu 1370 up
it seems to lower the MTU size.
However, the script under /etc/network/if-up.d is not automatically triggered.
Does something change with the newer Ubuntu version?

If you new fix works perhaps just update your original answer for 24.04?

no, it's not a fix, I'm trying to find one. It's not convenient to run manually every time the sudo ifconfig your_tunnel_name mtu 1370 up

Did you consider integrating your VPN connection with NetworkManager and just setting the MTU size in its settings? That would work on all Ubuntu versions (well, except server versions may not have NetworkManager, but I presume it is a desktop you're interested in, servers don't typically need to have VPN tunnel created inside).

Hi @Hi-Angel, yes, I integrated the VPN with networkManagaer. I can see it under VPN settings, it's a cisco compatible VPN. The problem is that I cannot see the MTU settings

I see. Offhand, I would presume it should be possible to edit the .nmconnection file for your connection under /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections and add an MTU setting there. I couldn't find out offhand what that setting would look like, but I presume it should be possible.

@Hi-Angel the only config file I am able to find is a <name>.pcf

ifconfig has been replaced with the ip command. Use something like ip link dev <your device> mtu 1492 . Read man ip ip-link.

@waltinator in the terminal however I can successfully run the command with ifconfig

Triggering if-up.d scripts changed completely without any documentation.
For 23.10 scripts was triggered for each network interface separately, on boot it was with

PHASE=post-up,IFACE=lo;
..., IFACE=virbr0;
..., IFACE=enx047bcb671ca9;
..., IFACE=docker0;
..., IFACE=wlp0s20f3
Later on connecting to openconnect/anyconnect it was triggered with
PHASE=post-up,IFACE=vpn0

After upgrade to 24.04 it is triggered on boot only with:

PHASE=post-up,IFACE=lo;
PHASE=post-up,IFACE=-all
Nothing triggered after connecting to VPN


Thanks @mirec! If you don't mind, could you post your answer also on ubuntu bug? I opened a bug here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/2064093

I managed to workaround it with NetworkManager-dispatcher. The doc can be found on arch.
The scripts must be moved from /etc/network/if-{up,down}.d/ to /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/. You can use the second argument $2 to branch on the specific event (up, down...).
Also, the usage of IFACE env var must be replaced with either VPN_IP_IFACE, DEVICE_IP_IFACE, or DEVICE_IFACE as applicable.
Note: Although networkd-dispatcher is a recommended modern way to trigger scripts, those were not executed on my Ubuntu 24.04 (desktop).

See the answer to this question for an example of a script using NetworkManager-dispatcher.
